# Scaling Systems With Shared Data

Tags: scalability, distributed-system

I'm working on an in memory on disk cache and am starting to think about strategies for scaling the system. At the moment the system persists data by creating a file for each key value pair, where the key is the filename and its contents are the value. I want to be able to scale the system horizontally but am unsure of the best approach. At the moment I am thinking of having each node store some of the values in cache. There would be a registry node which would be notified when a new value was added to the cache or when a value was deleted from the cache. The client would request this registry when first connecting to the cache so they knew where to get values from. A write to the cache would return which server the value was written to so the client would know where to read the value from(obviously this favors read performance over write performance as there would need to be a node which delegated the write requests)

Is this a good approach? or am I way off the mark

Edit(More Details):

I haven't gotten very far yet but I would like to build it in such a way that it could handle millions of files. I would also like to build it such a way that it can run using one node or as many nodes as can be provided. I know that doesn't clarify things a lot. I'm just trying to get some basic ideas so that as I build it I am at least sort of heading in the right direction. I'm also wondering if any people have some good insights into how existing systems do things like this. For example I know Casandra scales horizontally but haven't been able to find a great explanation of how

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887934/scaling-systems-with-shared-data "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Sorry, It was down voted and I assumed it meant I put it in the wrong place. I will delete that post

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and perhaps add some details on what you're doing?  Size of the files, number of files, number of nodes, etc. - as currently written, your question is very broad.

Comment: So right now your question is essentially "how do I scale horizontally?".  It's still very broad.  The right answer when you're starting out won't be the right answer when you have a million customers, and the right answer for a million customers will be too difficult and expensive to build when you're first starting out.  You need to carefully fit the size and complexity of your solution to your *immediate* needs, plus a small  bit of room for growth.  How big are the files, and how often would the "wrong" node need to read them?

Comment: I think it would be safe to assume most files would be approximately 1KB or less. There is no use case for this at the moment, it's just a side project for fun. In theory there should never be a wrong read as long as the client requests the registry upon connection. A write would always have to go to one node first and then be delegated to another node which would actually store and serve the data

Comment: To clarify further, I'm not looking for a "This is how to do it" answer. I'm more interested in implementations people have had experience with and how well they worked

Comment: This looks like a complex problem, aside from your very unclear description. You may need to look at some exsiting distributed systems, such as Hadoop. I know something like hadoop is not easy to implement. But you may get something by going through their high level design strategies.

Comment: You would benefit immensely by taking a look at how systems like Hbase (an in-memory on-disk key-value store designed for horizontal scalability) are architected. As it happens, the Hadoop distributed file system pretty much follows the design you have laid out, except that it is not designed for invalidating caches, so at least you are on the right track.